# How can I make an image size depend on its position?

Tags: html, css, image

How  would i make an image nested in a div to set its size depending on the div class.
making an image smaller depending where it is in the page. For example:

```
<div class="a">
    <img src="a.jpg">
<div>
<div class="b">
    <img src="a.jpg">
<div>
```

I would like to set the image nested in "a" to size 10X10 and the other to size 20X20, how would i do this without creating different classes for the images?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in yout css file add this:

```
.a img {width: 10px; height: 10px}
.b img {width: 20px; height: 20px}
```

this will make any image in "a" be of size 10X10 and any image in class "b" be of size 20X20.

Comment: This would work but the OP asked "how would i do this **without** creating different classes for the images?"

Comment: @andyb This example does exactly what OP asked for; styling the image based on it's parent container.

Comment: @Ross Yeah, I guess the question is slightly ambiguous. The OP does not want **different** classes for the images but semantically, the solution **does** have different classes for the images. That said, it is still a good (and possibly the only CSS) solution, so +1 to @nayish

Comment: Excellent, this is what i was looking for, i didn't know that this was possible. @andyb I ment that I wanted to do it without creating a specific class for each one of the images per div they are nested in, since I will have 15 of these on my page and it's enough work changing the name of the div class, now all i have to do is change the settings per nested img.

Comment: @Mike No problem, glad you got the answer you wanted :-)